# Разбиение массива изображения на блоки пикселей

Tags: java, графика

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм Дармстедтера-Делейгла на JAVA и столкнулся с неопределенной проблемой, в одной из его частей.

- Разбиение массива изображения-контейнера на блоки 8×8 пикселей

Собственно вопрос как нам получить двумерный массив пикселей из изображения, для того чтобы уже потом его делить на массивы 8х8?

Пожалуйста, натолкните на верную мысль.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211156/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array-in-java